# How do I output audio via USB?

Tags: usb, audio, pi-b

I installed OpenELEC on my RPi model B and now I want to connect a speaker to it. The speaker has a USB input. So, how do I do this? Do I need to get an external USB card or something else? Or do I just get a USB cable and connect the RPi to the speaker?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried plugging the speaker in to the Pi using a plain USB cable?

Comment: From what I read it seems I have to have a USB sound card before I attempt that. Or is that only for input?

Comment: I'm assuming that your speaker has a USB B connector of some sort. (See random picture I found online: http://blog.macsales.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/USB-BTYPES.jpg) If so, get a plain USB cable and plug it into your Pi, and see what happens. A USB sound card is for converting between analog and USB, but if your speaker has a USB connection, you don't need that. (You would use a USB sound card if you wanted to plug plain headphones into a USB connector.)